# Do you know Instagram automation Rules?

Tags: selenium, automation, instagram, bots

I want to write an instagram follower bot as a service , but i don't know any rules of instagram like time of delay between click on follow button or limit of account for one IP and ...

Do you know this rules ? or where i can find this rules ?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it in general it's about 180-200 request per 15 min, but ‌‌based on my experience it varies for different endpoints and you have to try it practically.